# API is not working after deploying on Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have created a weather application project based on react framework and the app gets its data from [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/).. and the project was completed successfully and it was running great on my localhost and after that i created a build folder and deployed at my firebase hosting platform but after deploying its not working only but the same API calls and codes are been running completely successfully at my local network , serve ... 
This is the deployed project : [CLICK](https://skysays-v01.web.app/)
This is the code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {ImSearch,ImLocation2} from 'react-icons/im';
import {AiOutlineReload} from 'react-icons/ai';
import {RiAlarmWarningLine} from 'react-icons/ri';
import axios from 'axios';
import './dataFetchStyle.css';

function DataFetching(){
    const [place,setPlace] = useState('');
    const [dataIN,setDataIN] = useState();
    const [fetchError,setFetchError] = useState(false);

    const APIKey = "/*my-key*/";
    const fetchData = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault(); 
        axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${place}&appid=${APIKey}`)
        .then(responce=>{
            setDataIN(responce)
            console.log(responce)
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
            setFetchError(true)
        })
        setPlace('')
    }
    const convertUTC = (UTC) =>{
        const fetchTime = new Date(UTC * 1000);
        const h = fetchTime.getHours();
        const m = fetchTime.getMinutes();
        return(h+":"+m)
    }
    if(!fetchError){
        return(
            <div className="ViewBox">
                <div className="SearchBox">
                    <form onSubmit={fetchData}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={place}
                            onChange={e=>{setPlace(e.target.value)}}
                            placeholder="Enter your place name..."/>
                        <button disabled={!place} type="submit"><ImSearch/></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                { dataIN ?
                    <div className="GotData">
                        <div className="showDataA">
                            <div className="NamePlace">
                                <h1>{dataIN.data.name}</h1>
                                <h2>{dataIN.data.sys.country}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <p>Geolocation : lon:{(dataIN.data.coord.lon).toFixed(1)} lat:{(dataIN.data.coord.lat).toFixed(1)}</p>
                            <p className="IMGP"><img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${dataIN.data.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`} alt="Icon"/></p>
                            <p className="mainTemp">{(dataIN.data.main.temp - 273.15).toFixed(1)}<span>&#8451;</span></p>
                            <p className="mainTempF">{((dataIN.data.main.temp - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32).toFixed(1)}<span>&#8457;</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="showDataB">
                            <p>min temp: {(dataIN.data.main.temp_min - 273.15).toFixed(1)}<span>&#8451;</span></p>
                            <p>max temp: {(dataIN.data.main.temp_max - 273.15).toFixed(1)}<span>&#8451;</span></p>
                            <p>humidity : {dataIN.data.main.humidity} %</p>
                            <p>pressure : {dataIN.data.main.pressure} hPa</p>
                            <p>visibility : {dataIN.data.visibility}  metres</p>
                            <p>wind speed : {dataIN.data.wind.speed} m/s</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="showDataC">
                            <h3>Other information</h3>
                            <hr/>
                            <p>sea level : {dataIN.data.main.sea_level} hPa</p>
                            <p>grnd level : {dataIN.data.main.grnd_level} hPa</p>
                            <p>wind deg : {dataIN.data.wind.deg}<span>&#176;</span></p>
                            <p>wind gust : {dataIN.data.wind.gust} m/s</p>
                            <p>sunrise : {convertUTC(dataIN.data.sys.sunrise)}</p>
                            <p>sunset : {convertUTC(dataIN.data.sys.sunset)}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div> : <p className="msgNA"><ImLocation2 color="rgba(255, 248, 220, 0.705)" size="50px"/></p>
                }
            </div> 
        )
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div className="OppsError">
                <p><RiAlarmWarningLine className="OppsErrorICON" size="35px"/></p>
                <p>
                Oops! , the place you have typed is not found <br/>
                so, please check your internet connection / the spelling or else we are sorry for your Inconvenience
                </p>
                <p><button onClick={()=>{setFetchError(!fetchError)}}><AiOutlineReload size="25px"/></button></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DataFetching;
```

Comment: what errors do **you** see in the browser console? hint, you can't access insecure API from secure web page - use `https://openweathermap.......` or just `//openweathermap......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the browser console, you should see the exact issue. Firebase servers content over HTTPS only and browsers would prevent using HTTP source then.

[image]

Change the URL to `https` instead of just `http`